# docker build fails when installing msodbcsql17

Tags: docker, unixodbc

I have a Dockerfile that built successfully two weeks ago.  I changed nothing and now get this error when I try to build:

```
#5 32.40 The following information may help to resolve the situation:
#5 32.40 
#5 32.40 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
#5 32.63  msodbcsql17 : Depends: unixodbc (>= 2.3.1) but it is not going to be installed
#5 32.67 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The relevant portion of the Dockerfile is:

```
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends \
        apt-transport-https \
        curl \
        gnupg \
        unixodbc-dev \
 && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
 && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/9/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
 && apt-get update \
 && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends msodbcsql17 \
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line:

```
        unixodbc-dev \
```

To:

```
        unixodbc \
```